# How to be notified when AKPlayer reaches a specified time

Tags: ios, audiokit

I have a need to detect when a specific time stamp is reached in an `AKPlayer`. When that point is reached, I move the playhead back to repeat a section of the song to support a vamp feature in the app.

My current approach is to use a `Timer` that's fired every millisecond to check if the `player.currentTime` has met or exceeded the specific time. The problem I see is the `currentTime` is not changing rapidly enough to detect this - it seems to update about every 11 milliseconds which isn't precise enough for my use case. The audio exceeds the time stamp before I catch it. Here you can see the value doesn't change each time the timer is fired, and when it does change it's a difference of 11.6 milliseconds, so if I needed to know when the player hit 0.5125 seconds, I wouldn't detect that until the player had run about 10 milliseconds over that time.

```
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5108390022675737
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
0.5224489795918368
```

Another option I explored was trying to observe the `currentTime` with KVO but unfortunately this is never invoked.

```
currentTimeObserver = player.observe(\.currentTime) { (player, change) in
    print("Changed to \(player.currentTime)")
}
```

Is there a way to more precisely track the `currentTime` or otherwise register to be notified when it reaches a specific time stamp?

Comment: Do you save the `currentTimeObserver` in a property? Or any other "long lived object"? Because if it is just a temporary object inside the function it would be removed with the removal of the scope itself.

Comment: Yes a property on the class